# Add condition for limitation of joinToString in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin

I have a list of string like this:

```
val texts = listOf("It is a",
                "long established fact that a reader will be distracted,",
                "by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.",
                "The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal",
                "distribution of letters, as opposed to using, making it look like readable English.",
                " Many desktop publishing packages and web page,",
                "editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search,",
                "for \'lorem ipsum\' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy",
                "Various versions have evolved over the years", ...)
```

I want to add a separator **" "** between them and limit the length of the result.

By using `joinToString` and `subString`, I can achieve the result.

```
texts.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
                .joinToString(separator = " ")
                .substring()
```

The question is: I want to use `joinToString` only and break the iterator whenever it reaches the **MAX_LENGTH** so it doesn't have to do any "joins" and `subString` after that.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `takeWhile` to limit the total length and then `join`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val texts = listOf("It is a",
            "long established fact that a reader will be distracted,",
            "by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.",
            "The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal",
            "distribution of letters, as opposed to using, making it look like readable English.",
            " Many desktop publishing packages and web page,",
            "editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search,",
            "for \'lorem ipsum\' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy",
            "Various versions have evolved over the years")

    val limit = 130
    var sum = 0
    val str = texts.takeWhile { sum += it.length + 1;  sum <= limit }.joinToString(" ")

    println(str)
    println(str.length)
}
```

will print

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted, by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
125
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

use `limit` parameter in `joinToString`

```
val substring = texts.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
                .joinToString(separator = " ", limit = 10, truncated = "")
                .substring(0)
```

Note `truncated` parameter to avoid `...` suffix.

Since original answer looking for `MAX_LENGTH` as final string length above solution won't work. Ideal one is `takeWhile` as in accepted answer. But it required to rely on external variables. I'd rather use functional approach if I could, but seems like there isn't one. So basically we need reduce operation with predicate, So slightly altered version of `reduce` would work

```
public inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduceWithPredicate(operation: (acc: S, T) -> S, predicate: (S) -> Boolean): S {
        val iterator = this.iterator()
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) throw UnsupportedOperationException("Empty collection can't be reduced.")
        var accumulator: S = iterator.next()
        while (iterator.hasNext() && predicate(accumulator)) {
            accumulator = operation(accumulator, iterator.next())
        }
        return accumulator
    }
```

Since we are dealing with string concatenation and trying to limit by its length, we have to use `substring` to get exact length but above inline function eleminates joining all elements and doesn't require intermediate list as in `takeWhile`. Also bit altered version of `takeWhile` would work

```
val joinedString = texts.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
                .reduceWithPredicate({ s1, s2 -> "$s1 $s2" }, { it.length < 100 })
                .substring(100)
assertTrue { joinedString.length < 100 }
```

Comment: Probably you should set the `truncated` property to the empty string, to avoid the `...` in the end of the `substring`

Comment: yes you are correct. will update the answer. thank you

Comment: limit = 10 will limit the size of array or limit the length of the result (which is a string) ?

Comment: It stops after 10 items joined. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want it stops whenever joined string reaches the MAX_LENGTH (for instance, 50 characters)